# Xcode analysis shows leak

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

When I analyse my code with Xcode,I have this error:

[image: Xcode error]

Thx for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it being confused by a method name `initDATAS` - it's a static analyzer so has to trust that you've named your methods following the standard pattern. In this case, methods beginning with `init` are reserved for initializing an object.

Try changing it to `configDATAS` instead and see what happens?

Other than that, you're doing everything correctly!

PS Are you testing on the simulator or on a real device - the simulator will return false positives sometimes so you should always check on an iPhone :)